# Why is there no *ForKeyPath in objC?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

Why is there valueForKey: and intForKey:, stringForKey:, etc.

but there is valueForKeyPath: and no intForKeyPath:, stringForKeyPath:, etc.?

Comment: It's because apple wants programmers to use their skills

Comment: you can add it with a category if you want to

Answer (score 1):

Apple's `NSDictionary` does not support messages named `intForKey:` or `stringForKey:`.

Perhaps you are using some third-party library that adds those messages in a category.  You could ask the author of that library why she didn't include keypath versions of the messages.

Perhaps you are thinking of `NSUserDefaults`, not `NSDictionary`.  `NSUserDefaults` understands `integerForKey:` and `stringForKey:`.  `NSUserDefaults` is not intended for storing large, complex structures.  It is intended for storing small, simple pieces of data.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the method names from 2 different objects (actually, 1 object and one informal protocol): `NSUserDefaults` and the [`NSKeyValueCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003780) informal protocol.

`NSUserDefaults` has been around for ages, while key-value-coding and key-value-observing have only been around since OS X 10.3.

`NSUserDefaults` deals with storing property-list-compatible objects (NSData, NSDate, NSString, NSArray, and NSDictionary) for persistence between app launches. Apps often need to store non-object type values like BOOLs or ints, yet only objects are supported, so these convenience methods (`intForKey:`, `boolForKey:`, etc.) allow a more concise way of saving them. For example, the following line of code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:MDFirstLaunchKey];
```

becomes:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:MDFirstLaunchKey];
```

The corresponding "get" methods allow more concise code to obtain the non-object type values .

Another purpose of these methods in `NSUserDefaults` is validation of object types. Let's say you have saved an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s under the key `MDClientsKey`, and you mistakenly write the following code:

```
NSDictionary *client = [userDefaults objectForKey:MDClientsKey];
NSString *name = [client objectForKey:@"name"];
```

The dynamic nature of Objective-C means that the object user defaults would return for that `objectForKey:` call would not be an `NSDictionary` as the code assumes, but would be an `NSArray`. The subsequent line would try to call `objectForKey:` on an NSArray, which would likely raise an NSInvalidArgumentException and cause the app to crash.

If you had instead used [`dictionaryForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/dictionaryForKey%3a), `NSUserDefaults` would have returned `nil`:

```
NSDictionary *client = [userDefaults dictionaryForKey:MDClientsKey];
NSString *name = [client objectForKey:@"name"];
```

The subsequent line would then mean you were sending a message to `nil`, which is simply ignored (in other words, no crash).

On the other hand, the `valueForKey:` and `valueForKeyPath:` methods are part of the `NSKeyValueCoding` informal protocol. They basically allow one object to access another's instance variables by name using an `NSString` rather than by having to call a method. A key part of this is that `valueForKey:` and `valueForKeyPath:` need to return objects, not primitive types like `int` or `float`, etc. In fact, if an object has a `height` property that is a primitive type like `NSInteger`, calling `[object valueForKeyPath:@"height"]` will [automatically wrap](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-184696-BCIIJJGE) it to return an `NSNumber`. Because of this, it wouldn't really make much sense to have the extended `*ForKeyPath:` accessors.